# calling css code in different folder

Tags: html, css, apache

My folder setup

-src/main/html/index.html

-src/main/css/global.css

Just in case it is relevent, I have apache24 setup to look for

`DocumentRoot "/home/master/Documents/projects/SCI/src/main/html.`

So finally, in my index.html I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/global.css" />
```

My problem is that my css doesn't work unless I put my global.css in the html folder and do a straight "href="global.css". Other than that, I have tried setting href to "/css/global.css", "css/global.css", "/../css/global.css", "global.css" and "/css/global.css". What should I make my href be to get my css code

Edit: It appears that it is dropping the ".." on run time. If I inspect element from my webpage, it reads "The requested URL /css/global.css was not found on this server"

Comment: You should follow the link in your browser to see where it's pointing right now and adjust. You can inspect the link using your Dev Tools.

Comment: @JonUleis apparently "../css/global.css" is looking in "http://127.0.0.1//css/global.css"

Comment: look at your Apache  settings or search if there is any .htaccess file in your main dir it could have some codes mess the dir , then move your html inside new folder and name it `site` for example then inser this in your index and tell me the result : `<script>alert(window.location.href); </script>`

Answer (score 0):

Answer found, It is an Apache "issue." Apache won't let you go further then the "DocumentRoot." So by setting my root to ".../html", I can't look past ".../html", only forward; so regardless of how many "../'s" I add into my code, I can't look further back then the html file.

The solution was to set DocumentRoot to ".../src/main/" and navigate to localhost/html. That way, "../css/global.css" can now make it back to see the css folder.